# Algorithm count of independent sets, always down by 1

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm having trouble writing an algorithm to count the number of independent sets in a tree. (An independent set is where any two nodes have no edge between them.)

Here is my java class for ListNode:

```
 1public class ListNode
 2{
 3    private Object data;
 4    private ListNode next;
 5
 6    public ListNode(Object data, ListNode next)
 7    {
 8        this.data = data;
 9        this.next = next;
10    }
11
12    public Object getData()  {return data;}
13    public ListNode getNext(){return next;}
14    public void setNext(ListNode n){next = n;}
15    public void setData(Object d){data = d;}
16    public boolean search(ListNode l, Object o)
17    {
18        while (l != null){
19            if (l.getData().equals(o))
20                return true;
21            l = l.getNext();
22        }
23        return false;
24    }
25    public static ListNode rev(ListNode curr)
26    {
27        ListNode rev = null;
28        while (curr != null){
29            rev = new ListNode(curr.getData(), rev);
30            curr = curr.getNext();
31        }
32        return rev;}}
```

And my java class for the TreeNode:

```
1public class TreeNode
 2{   ListNode children = null;
 3    public void addChild(TreeNode t)
 4    {
 5        if (children == null)
 6            children = new ListNode(t, null);
 7        else{
 8            ListNode curr = children;
 9            while (curr.getNext() != null)
10                curr = curr.getNext();
11            curr.setNext(new ListNode(t, null));
12        }}
13    public void setChildren(ListNode t){this.children = t;}
14    public int numStableSet()
15    {
16
17        if (children == null || children.getNext() == null)
18            return 2;
19        else{
20            int count = 2;
21            setChildren(children.getNext());
22            count *= numStableSet();
23            return count;
24        }
25    }
```

The method numStableSet is the one where I need some coding help. As it is set up now, it prints out 1 less than the correct answer. I also haven't figured out the case where each Node could be a tree itself.

Help appreciated

Comment: Perhaps the obvious answer, but couldn't you just return/output whatever you get `+1`?

Comment: @Link Ya, I thought about that but I'm not sure where to put the +1 as the algorithm needs to be a recursive one. Putting the +1 in the wrong spot results in overshooting the correct answer.

Comment: I suspect that you could/should put it in the place where the final result is just about to be returned?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand your code... How does this resemble a Tree and not just a LinkedList? And why do you have a ListNode and a TreeNode? Wouldn't you just want to have a (Tree)Node class which has a List<(Tree)Node> children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't trust that your algorithm will always be off by one. Let's consider a few example cases, starting with the most simple ones.

- No node => 1 independent set, the empty set
- One node => 2 independent set, empty and the one node
- One parent and its sole child => 3 independent sets, empty and either node

Since your code seems to give the same result of 2 for both the single node and the node with single child, I believe your code to be wrong.

Now let's consider the recursive case, to find the right algorithm. You are currently visiting a given node. You could decide to *not* include that node in the stable set, then visit all its children and choose arbitrary stable sets for these. Or you could decide to include the current node, but only if its own parent was not included, and when recursing to the children you have to ensure not to count those. Keep track of all the possible ways to combine these choices, and you have your count. In pythonic pseudocode:

```py
def combinationsWithoutCurrent(current):
  num = 1
  for child in current:
    num *= stableSet(child)
  return num

def combinationsWithCurrent(current):
  num = 1
  for child in current:
    num *= combinationsWithoutCurrent(child)
  return num

def stableSet(current):
  return (combinationsWithCurrent(current) +
          combinationsWithoutCurrent(current))
```

As you prefer Java and obscure hand-made container classes, here is some Java code on how I guess your data structures are intended. Since you never call `getData` in the tree traversal, I can't see any actual recursion going on in your code. So my guess might be wrong.

```
private int combinationsWithoutCurrent() {
  int num = 1;
  for (ListNode iter = children; iter != null; iter = iter.getNext())
    num *= ((TreeNode)iter.getData()).numStableSets();
  return num;
}

private int combinationsWithCurrent() {
  int num = 1;
  for (ListNode iter = children; iter != null; iter = iter.getNext())
    num *= ((TreeNode)iter.getData()).combinationsWithoutCurrent();
  return num;
}

public int numStableSet() {
  return combinationsWithCurrent() + combinationsWithoutCurrent();
}
```